# Shift-selection when navigating tabs in elpy (Emacs Python plugin)

Tags: python, emacs

I have recently set up elpy under Emacs 24, and everything works great except one feature which I haven't been able to figure out:

My settings are very close to the default ones, with cua-mode and transient-mark-mode enabled - and that means that everywhere except when editing Python files I can highlight words with CTRL+Shift+.

When editing Python files, CTRL+ is mapped to elpy-nav-[forward|backward]-indent (jumping between indentation levels), but isn't compatible with pressing the Shift key to highlight my selection.

I know it sounds like a very small matter - but it's driving me crazy :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il look like there are too many "opinionated" bindings competing for few "hot" keys.
I reduced some binding to avoid overriding my favourite ones (ctr/alt arrows)

Using the *"great"* **use-package**:

- https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package

I avoided keybinding conflicts between **elpy** and **cua-mode**

I lost some elpy defaults:

```
(use-package elpy
  :ensure t
  :preface
  (defvar elpy-mode-map
    (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
      ;; Alphabetical order to make it easier to find free C-c C-X
      ;; bindings in the future. Heh.

      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<backspace>") 'python-indent-dedent-line-backspace)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<backtab>")   'python-indent-dedent-line)

      ;; (define-key map (kbd "C-M-x")   'python-shell-send-defun)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "C-c <")   'python-indent-shift-left)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "C-c >")   'python-indent-shift-right)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c RET") 'elpy-importmagic-add-import)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-b") 'elpy-nav-expand-to-indentation)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-d") 'elpy-doc)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-e") 'elpy-multiedit-python-symbol-at-point)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-f") 'elpy-find-file)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-n") 'elpy-flymake-next-error)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-o") 'elpy-occur-definitions)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-p") 'elpy-flymake-previous-error)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-s") 'elpy-rgrep-symbol)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-t") 'elpy-test)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-v") 'elpy-check)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-z") 'elpy-shell-switch-to-shell)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-r i") 'elpy-importmagic-fixup)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-r p") 'elpy-autopep8-fix-code)
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-r r") 'elpy-refactor)

      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<S-return>") 'elpy-open-and-indent-line-below)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<C-S-return>") 'elpy-open-and-indent-line-above)

      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<C-return>") 'elpy-shell-send-current-statement)

      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<C-down>") 'elpy-nav-forward-block)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<C-up>") 'elpy-nav-backward-block)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<C-left>") 'elpy-nav-backward-indent)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<C-right>") 'elpy-nav-forward-indent)

      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<M-down>") 'elpy-nav-move-line-or-region-down)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<M-up>") 'elpy-nav-move-line-or-region-up)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<M-left>") 'elpy-nav-indent-shift-left)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<M-right>") 'elpy-nav-indent-shift-right)

      ;; (define-key map (kbd "M-.")     'elpy-goto-definition)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "M-TAB")   'elpy-company-backend)

      (define-key map (kbd "<S-return>") 'elpy-open-and-indent-line-below)
      (define-key map (kbd "<C-S-return>") 'elpy-open-and-indent-line-above)

      (define-key map (kbd "<C-return>") 'elpy-shell-send-current-statement)

      (define-key map (kbd "<M-right>") 'elpy-nav-forward-block)
      (define-key map (kbd "<M-left>") 'elpy-nav-backward-block)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<C-S-left>") 'elpy-nav-backward-indent)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<C-S-right>") 'elpy-nav-forward-indent)

      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<M-S-down>") 'elpy-nav-move-line-or-region-down)
      ;; (define-key map (kbd "<M-S-up>") 'elpy-nav-move-line-or-region-up)
      (define-key map (kbd "<M-S-left>") 'elpy-nav-indent-shift-left)
      (define-key map (kbd "<M-S-right>") 'elpy-nav-indent-shift-right)

      (define-key map (kbd "M-.")     'elpy-goto-definition)
      (define-key map [(control menu)]   'elpy-company-backend)

      map)
    "Key map for the Emacs Lisp Python Environment.")
  :config
  (elpy-enable)
  (elpy-use-ipython)
  (defalias 'workon 'pyvenv-workon))

(use-package ein
  :ensure t
  :config
  (defalias 'eip 'ein:notebooklist-open))
```

See:

- https://github.com/hute37/emacs-site/blob/master/site-pkgs.el#L481

Comment: I had to change also **Ctrl-C** to **Meta-C** to avoid conflict with CUA "Copy", when selection is active.